# Regular expression: match a word of certain length which starts with certain letters

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex which matches a `7` letter word, which starts with `'st'`. 
For example, it should only match `'startin'` out of the following: `start startin starting`

Answer (score 5):

General tips:

- The starting symbols are included into the regex directly, e.g. `st`. 
  If the starting characters are special in the sense of regex-syntax (like dots, parentheses, etc.), you need to escape them with a backslash, but it is not needed in your case.
- After the starting symbols, include *character class* for the remaining characters of your "word". If you want to allow all characters, use a dot: `.`. If you want to allow all non-whitespace characters, use `\S`. If you want to allow only (unicode) letters, use `\p{L}`. To only allow non-accented latin letters, use `[A-Za-z]`. There are many possibilities here.
- Finally, include *repetition quantifier* for the character class from the previous step. In you case, you need exactly 5 characters after `st`, so the repetition quantifier is `{5}`.
- If you want only the whole string to match, use `\A` at the beginning and `\z` at the end of your regex. Or include `\b` at the beginning/end of your regex to match at the so-called *word boundaries* (including start/end of the string, whitespace, punctuation). 
  The most powerful alternative (with full control) is the so-called *lookahead* - I'll leave it out here for the sake of simplicity.

See [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for details. You can just look for specific keywords I've mentioned, e.g. *repetition*, *character class*, *unicode*, *lookahead*, etc.

Comment: Better use `\b`  instead of lookaround assertions. It's easier.

Answer (score 1):

To match words with non-accent characters that are case insensitive you'll need the `i` modifier or you'll need to declare both letters at the beginning in both cases.

```
<?php

    $regex = '!\bst[a-z]{5}\b!i';
    $words = "start startin starting station Stalker SHOWER Staples Stiffle Steerin StÄbles'";
    preg_match_all($regex,$words,$matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => startin
    [1] => station
    [2] => Stalker
    [3] => Staples
    [4] => Stiffle
    [5] => Steerin
)
```

With the same output as above, if you didn't use the `i` modifier you would have to declare more characters:

```
$regex = '!\b[Ss][Tt][A-Za-z]{5}\b!';
```

If you want to match Unicode Characters you can do this:

```
print "<meta charset=\"utf-8\"><body>";

    $regex = '!\bst([a-z]|[^u0000-u0080]){5}\b!iu';

    $words = "start startin starting station Stalker SHOWER Staples Stiffle Steerin StÄbles'";

    preg_match_all($regex,$words,$matches);

    print_r($matches[0]);

print "</body>";
```

**Output**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => startin
    [1] => station
    [2] => Stalker
    [3] => Staples
    [4] => Stiffle
    [5] => Steerin
    [6] => StÄbles //without UTF-8 output it looks like this-> StÃ"bles
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/\bst\w{5}\b/', 'start startin starting', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

UPDATE:  used word boundaries before and after, based on comment

Comment: Would match `startin` in `astartin`. Would not match in `startin.` or if `startin` was at the end of the string/line. Perhaps `\b` instead? And have it at beginning & end?

Comment: Would match `st34567`, Use [a-z] & i instead or [a-zA-Z]

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I tried to leave it more broad until we get clarification from OP on what's allowed in the string.  However, I agree with you that if it is literally just "letters" then your suggestion would make sense.