# Regex match character in words of certain length

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I am trying to create a regex that matches a set of characters in a word of a certain length.

AKA with list of `hello goodbye low loving`

Word length of 5 or greater 
Match character of l [it would match `l l l` (the two in the `hello` and the one in the `loving`)].

I need this for a replace use case.

Therefore replace letter as `£` would output

`he££o goodbye low £oving`

I was referring to this question, [regular-expression-match-a-word-of-certain-length-which-starts-with-certain-let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406591/regular-expression-match-a-word-of-certain-length-which-starts-with-certain-let), but I can't work out how to change the matching symbol from the whole word to a character in the word.

I have, but I need to add the word length check to the matching regex.

```
myText = myText.replace(/l/g, "£");
```

Comment: Please, write more: what replacements should be done? `heRo goodbye low Roving` ?

Comment: Provide an input and an expected output. Post the code which does not do what it is supposed to.

Comment: Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/ynKdh/). Is this what you want?

Comment: edited... the code is pretty minimal as the only bit I am missing is the regex.

Comment: @Harry... I had thought about this two step approach. But I want to save having to rebuild the string I need to return each time, curse the immutable string :P !

Comment: @tigerswithguitars: Ok, but I already posted it as an answer :D. I will leave it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function like this:

```
var str = 'hello goodbye low loving';
var res = str.replace(/\b(?=\S*l)\S{5,}/g, function(m) {
    return m.replace(/l/g, "£");
});
alert(res);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unknown008/K2wTa/)

I'm using the lookahead just so that the anonymous function is not called for every single 5 (or more) letter word.

EDIT: A regex a little faster is: `\b(?=[^\sl]*l)\S{5,}`

And if JS ever supports possessive quantifiers, this will even faster: `\b(?=[^\sl]*+l)\S{5,}`

---

Explanation of regex

```
\b         // matches a word boundary; prevents checks in the middle of words
(?=        // opening of positive lookahead
   [^\sl]* // matches all characters except `l` or spaces/newlines/tabs/etc
   l       // matches a single l; if matched, word contains at least 1 `l`
)          // closing of positive lookahead
\S{5,}     // retrieves word on which to run the replace
```

Comment: Any use of the ? is pretty sexy, but may make the whole thing a bit sluggish on large words and big text? I guess I will have to add it to the tests.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars You can speed it up a little with `[^\sl]*` instead of `\S*`. If JS supported possessive quantifiers, that'd speed it up even more :)

Comment: @Jerry... don't suppose you know of any documentation that explains this? I like the recipe, but I want to at least try to understand it.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars Sure. The site the most quoted around here, and the page describing possessive quantifiers is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). Basically, what makes regex slow is backtracking and testing the same thing again (like a stubborn machine convinced there is a match which looks for every single possibility without thinking completely logically) Possessive quantifiers prevent backtracking, so that the regex won't check as much as it initially was.

Comment: Even with backtracking it was faster than my answer, so +1 for that; this expression is harder to understand, though :)

Comment: @Jack That's a downside I can't deny ^^; I guess I could add a full explanation to my answer to make it more proper. Ok, I'll work on it now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var s='hello goodbye low loving';
r = s.replace(/\S{5,}/g, function(r) { return r.replace(/l/g, '£'); } );
// he££o goodbye low £oving
```

Comment: Nested replace with anonymous function! Very neat, I didn't know you could do this. Looks good.